# Как указать путь к каталогу в .bat файле?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

У меня есть .bat файл, рядом лежит папка (Result).
В папке лежат .jpg файлы с разными именами.
Я пытаюсь написать .bat файле чтобы он все эти файлы в этой папке переименовал.
Он работает, но не полностью. Вот в чём проблема:
 **Он работает только в том каталоге, в котором находятся файлы. 
(Мне нужен .bat файл и папка с файлами рядом с ним. Что-бы так работал).**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=1000"
set a="Result\*.jpg"
for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`) do (ren "%%f" file-!count:~1!.jpg
set /a count+=1
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот решение..**
Можно просто зайти в папку прописав путь `cd /d Result`

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d Result
set "count=1000"
set a="*.jpg"
for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`) do (ren "%%f" file-!count:~1!.jpg
set /a count+=1
)
pause
```

**SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion** Раскрытие переменных через знаки (!)
**cd /d Result** заходим в папку Result
**set "count=1000"** переменная в которой я обозначил количество нулей *file-001.jpg*
**set a="*.jpg"** переменная обозначает какие файлы ищем.

(`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`)
**dir** - Позволяет отобразить список файлов и подкаталогов. Далее сортируем.
**/b** - Вывод только имен файлов.
**/o:-d** - Сортировка списка отображаемых файлов в обратном порядке (от новых к старым).
**/tc** - Сортировать по времени создания файла.
**%a%** - Вызываем переменную.

**usebackq** Задает возможность использования кавычек для имен файлов *Такие вот>* **"**.
Задает исполнение строки, заключенной в обратные кавычки, как команды*Такие вот>* **`**,
а строки в одиночных кавычках — как команды в символьной строке*Такие вот>* **'**.

**delims=xxx** Задает набор разделителей. Заменяет набор разделителей по умолчанию, состоящий из пробела и символа табуляции.

Возможно есть и другие решения, такие как:

```
pushd "D:\каталог01\каталог02"
dir
pause
:: Команда "popd" в случае необходимости вернёт в качестве текущей директорию,
:: которая была таковой до применения команды "pushd" (используется только с ней в паре).
popd
```